# pandas - index information lost after iloc[2,:]

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I got a class which similar as bellow code, it maintains a pandas frame of states, in my real case is much more complex than this given, so I need to create several algorithm based filters to find out one of my required record.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

class stateMachine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.contextStack = pd.DataFrame(columns=['state',
                    'end_date', 'speed',
                    'weight', 'area'])
        self.state = 'idle'
        self.day = dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days=100)

    def update(self):
        state_ctx = {
                    'state': self.state,
                    'end_date':self.day,
                    'speed': self.speed ,
                    'weight':self.weight
                }
        df = pd.DataFrame([state_ctx])
        self.contextStack = pd.concat([self.contextStack, df], ignore_index=True)
        self.day = self.day + dt.timedelta(days=1)
    
    def set_speed(self, speed):
        self.speed = speed
    
    def set_weight(self, weight):
        self.weight = weight
        
    def set_state(self, state):
        self.state = state
```

Here is a very simple example code to add up items like:

```
sm = stateMachine()

states = ['idle', 'on', 'off']

for i in range(0, 10):
    sm.set_speed(i)
    sm.set_weight(i+100)
    sm.set_state(states[i%3])
    sm.update()
```

So after run this, I get my dataframes:

```
state   end_date    speed   weight
0   idle    2022-01-24  0   100
1   on  2022-01-25  1   101
2   off 2022-01-26  2   102
3   idle    2022-01-27  3   103
4   on  2022-01-28  4   104
5   off 2022-01-29  5   105
6   idle    2022-01-30  6   106
7   on  2022-01-31  7   107
8   off 2022-02-01  8   108
9   idle    2022-02-02  9   109
```

my current algorithm can find one selected item, it looks like:

```
    def get_filtered_stack(self, state):
        filtered_df = self.contextStack[(self.contextStack['state']==state)]
        return filtered_df

    def find_item_understate(self, state, weight, speed):
        self.state_stack = self.get_filtered_stack(state)
        # after some operation, I get a index of wanted
        # let's assume it is 0
        ctx = self.state_stack.iloc[0,:]
        return ctx
```

**Here comes my problem,** after my higher level application got this 'ctx' and later it no longer be able to address back it's index in the original whole pandas dataframe.

```
context = sm.find_item_understate('on', 104, 4)
```

because the 'index' information is lost after 'iloc', here is the test context from above code looks like:

```
state               on
end_date    2022-01-25
speed                1
weight             101
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

In some cases, I need to find back the original index in my later process, in this case, it is 1.

But since the context already lost 'index' information, it causes a trouble to me that, in the end of the day, the out context lost the way back home.

*note: the date/speed/weight columns can't be refered as a filter to address back the index.*

Comment: why don't you do a reset_index has a column ? if you lose the old index ?

Comment: Hi @DataSciRookie, I am afraid you do not understand the problem, just to explain, my index is already in sequence, this is because everytime when I concat, I add ignore_index=True as parameter. the problem is, I need to find back the original index from 'big dataframe'

Comment: just to be sure you have pd.concat([self.contextStack, df], ignore_index=True) but you want to keep the index one of them, right ?

Comment: nop, there is an index generated for each item during concat, this is not the focus, the problem is after my filter algorithms, which eventually will give out a single item as 'context' demonstrated by my code. but after the 'context'  given out, how can I address back the index(generated at concat time) by the 'context'? For 'context' please refer to my example code.

Comment: Hi @DataSciRookie, I eventually figure out this problem! In my case, after my returned 
 filtered series to a third party class or program, there is actually a member 'Name' holds the index. so just Ctx.name, that is it!